# Viewport issues

Tags: 3d-view

I'm pretty new to blender. I tried to find the answer to my problem without success... My viewport suddenly started to act weird. When I'm in object mode I didn't get the yellow diqplay to show what is the selected object. When I add a light, I can't see it in the display also. The light exist and I can tweak the values or rotate or scale but I have no icone to represent it in the viewport. When I'm in shading viewport My model is crop for no apparent reason. Same thing in the wireframe view. I tried to quit and relaunch but I got the same problem. Do you have any advice or solution with that?
[image]

Comment: Make sure that *Show Overlays* is enabled and set the clipping values to a sensible range (or reduce the scale of the model).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already tried that and nothing changes. There was no such problem for a while and then it appears suddenly without any new manipulation from myself.

Comment: Then please add a full screenshot of your entire user interface.

Comment: I put it in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

It looks like you accidentally set a *clipping region* in the viewport. The shortcut for this is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. Press that again and you should see everything.

As for the outline around selected objects, they may reappear once the clipping region is removed. Otherwise, double check that *Outline Selected* is still enabled in the overlays menu at the top right of the viewport.

Comment: OOOOk.... That was the thing... Thank you for your help. That was one of those little things you struggle with when you start to learn a new software... 
Have a nice day thought!